# How to change button text in system dialogs(openFileDialog,SaveFileDialog)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I must provide my project with multi language.In my project i use common dialogs,which i dont know how to change button texts according to language.But i find this [project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx) .I dont know how to use it.Please help me with this.Regards

Comment: aren't those dialogs already localized? That's part of the point of them, I thought.

Comment: they localized.but when i want to change only projets's language theirs language will not change

Comment: How do you change only project language?

Comment: I change it manually:titles,contents..

Answer (score 1):

You must open the dialog with the right culture on the thread.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

This will show the dialog in the language you want.

On the other hand I think it is a bad idea doing manually multilingual support. You are spending time doing things that other already did, tested, documented and supported.

Comment: I forget to write the solution which I had found that time. I needed to modify only strings on dialogs like "OK", "Cancel" WLOG, only in program, not language of machine. I found some build-in methods in user32.dll to set these strings,  on opened dialogs and it worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

That link is to customize the dialog functionality as it says `you could add extra buttons..` but not to change the already existing elements

I think that the only option is to create your own dialog